# Delete rows that contain NULLs if row with ID already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table as shown below.

If a product id has been entered into the table with a description, I want to delete all other rows with the same product ids where the description is `NULL`, leaving only the product id with a description. In the table below, I want to delete `ROW_ID = 1` and keep `ROW_ID = 2`.

Furthermore, if a row is present with product id with a `NULL` description but no other matching product ids, I want to leave that row in the table. In the table below leaving `ROW_ID = 3` as it is.

| row_id | product_id | product_description | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000001 | null | 2012-12-22 20:00:00 |
| 2 | 000001 | item description | 2012-12-23 21:00:00 |
| 3 | 000002 | null | 2012-12-23 21:00:00 |

The resulting table would look like this:

| row_id | product_id | product_description | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 000001 | item description | 2012-12-23 21:00:00 |
| 3 | 000002 | null | 2012-12-23 21:00:00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this assuming the table is named `products`:

```sql
DELETE FROM products as p
WHERE p.product_description is null
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM products as p2 WHERE p2.product_id = p.product_id AND p2.product_description IS NOT NULL
);
```

The `EXISTS` operator will return true if the subselect returns greater than 0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
WITH    cte
AS ( SELECT   * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id order by time_stamp desc) as rn
    FROM     t)

DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  rn>1 and cte.product_description is null;

select * from t;
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f81b3/3)